# Display an image read from a zip archive python

Tags: python, image, zip, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I want to create a comic archive reader in python as an exercise to teach myself more python but I've been having troubles trying to read different image files from a zip archive without extracting the files and then display them.

I found a website with an example (http://www.python-forum.org/pythonforum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=3607) that could only display .gif images. The example uses `PhotoImage` (The Tkinter version not the PIL version) which can accept a 64bit encoded string instead of an actual file. From most of my research it looks like PIL is what I want to use to deal with images other than gif but I can't find a way to call `PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage` in a similar way to the `Tkinter.PhotoImage`. to take a stream of data instead of an actual file.

Is there any way that I can hand the data received from `zipfile.read()` to `PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage`? Is there another library I could use to handle the images? Tkinter is not a requirement for the program I'm writing so if there is a better widget framework that I should be using I don't mind changing.

EDIT:
So I figured a way to do this with PIL and tkinter.

```
z = zipfile.ZipFile("zipfile.zip", "r")

data = z.read(z.namelist()[0])    #Read in the first image data
dataEnc = StringIO(data)          #Encode the raw data to be used by Image.open()

img = Image.open(dataEnc)         #Open the image
pimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)    #Make tk compatible image
```

Comment: Probably a good time to break out [`StringIO`](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html) for some testing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PythonMagick to create an `Image` like so:

```
from PythonMagick import *

data = zipfile.read()
img = Image(Blob(data))
```

Then display it using wxPython as suggested in the PythonMagick [readme](http://www.imagemagick.org/download/python/README.txt) under the "Display" section.

Comment: Or if you're lazy just pipe the image data to the ``display -`` command.